# Drag'n'Drop sortable Listbox for Windows Phone 7

Tags: user-controls, drag-and-drop, windows-phone-7

I got a ListBox containing a few items in a Windows Phone 7 application. I want the user to be able to sort the items in the ListBox by just touching and dragging them (on the left part of the ListBox template).

How would I implement this? Is there a standard way or control to get this kind of drag and drop functionality (preferably even with animation) on Windows Phone 7?

Or is there some other control / panel which is better to use than ListBox?

Comment: I was looking for the same thing. It seems to be that you have to write your own code. At this time there is no standard control available. Probably you will find some hints here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SL4DragDropListBox.aspx?pageflow=Fluid&fid=1572066&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick It's a Silverlight 4 implementation.

Comment: What did you end up doing, I am trying to find a solution to the same thing.

Comment: I endet up postponing the project until the platform is ready :)