# Does Windows Phone has equivalent of iPhone SDK listview for sorting manually?

Tags: windows-phone-7

On iPhone listview can be sorted MANUALLY by dragging and dropping. Does Windows Phone sdk has something equivalent to this ?

If not is there a component somewhere free if possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate? Rather old though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021915/dragndrop-sortable-listbox-fur-windows-phone-7

Comment: Yes but I got a more interesting answer so it's worth re-asking: the other is just ugly listbox not really fancy like iphone or the component below and 2°) the other is classical drag and drop between TWO listsnot within the same list ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Bewise controls offer the thing you need, please take a look at its OrderableList. http://bewisephonecontrols.codeplex.com/

Comment: Wonderfull seems what I'm looking for :)