# Can I drag and drop listed items somehow?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, gesture

This seems impossible until now: I would like to list items in a (no matter how) listBox, with the ability to drag on items on top of another item.

When I have 1, 2, 3 listed in a listBox, I would like to be able to drag the 3 onto the 2 and recognize that event, to create a item "5".

Comment: not a straight solution, only a [possible helpful information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021915/dragndrop-sortable-listbox-fur-windows-phone-7)